# How to set the LD_PRELOAD environment variable for a ptrace child

Tags: linux, ptrace, ld-preload

I'm trying to load a pre-load library to the ptrace child process using environment variables. But somehow I got an error when creating the child process:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *env[] = {"LD_PRELOAD=/<path-to-the-preload-library>/preload.so"};
    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
        case -1: /* error */
            log_fatal("%s. pid -1", strerror(errno));
            break;
        case 0:  /* child, executing the tracee */
            ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
            execve(argv[1], argv + 1, env); // Fail to launch ptrace child!
            //execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);    // It works fine!
            log_fatal("%s. child", strerror(errno));
    }

    waitpid(pid, 0, 0); // sync with PTRACE_TRACEME
    ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0, PTRACE_O_EXITKILL);
```

The simple preloaded library code:

```
$ cat preload.c
#include <stdio.h>

static void _init() __attribute__((constructor));
void _init() {
    printf("I'm a constructor\n");
}
```

Any idea why it fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be nice if you told us *what* the error message was, but I think I can guess: "Bad address"?

The `env` vector passed to `execve` needs to be terminated with a NULL pointer, just like the `argv` vector.  So you want

```
char *env[] = {"LD_PRELOAD=/<path-to-the-preload-library>/preload.so", NULL};
```

Comment: Yes. The error is "Bad Address". The problem is fixed. Thanks!